# Remove or Filter values out of an Array using for loop or a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have an Array and i would like to  Filter or delete the following urls from my Array every time they appear:

```
"https://basueUrl.com/Claim"
"https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit"
```

My Array

```
Array= [  
        "https://basueUrl.com/Patient"
        "https://basueUrl.com/Organization"
        "https://basueUrl.com/Claim"
        "https://basueUrl.com/Practitioner"
        "https://basueUrl.com/Encounter"
        "https://basueUrl.com/Condition"
        "https://basueUrl.com/Claim"
        "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit"
        "https://basueUrl.com/Claim"
        "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit" 
        "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit"
        ]
```

**First Solution** I have tried for loop but did not work?

```
   for( var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++){ 
   if ( Array[i] === "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit" & "https://basueUrl.com/Claim") {
    Array.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
   }
}
console.log(Array);
```

**Second Solution** I tried making a remove method did not work either.

```
function arrayRemove(Array, value) {

   return Array.filter(function(ele){
       return ele != value;
   });
}
var result = arrayRemove(Array,"https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit" & "https://basueUrl.com/Claim");
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is modifying the array while the loop is being executed, which generates problem with the index because the `array.length` changes when you call `Array.prototype.splice`.

In the second approach, you're not passing what you think

```js
console.log("https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit" & "https://basueUrl.com/Claim"); 
// A number? probably you want an array.
```

You can use the function `filter` and the function `includes` as follow:

```js
let skip = ["https://basueUrl.com/Claim", "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit"];
let arr = ["https://basueUrl.com/Patient","https://basueUrl.com/Organization","https://basueUrl.com/Claim","https://basueUrl.com/Practitioner","https://basueUrl.com/Encounter","https://basueUrl.com/Condition","https://basueUrl.com/Claim","https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit","https://basueUrl.com/Claim","https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit","https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit"];
let result = arr.filter(url => !skip.includes(url));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.filter(x => x !== "https://basueUrl.com/Claim" && x !== "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit")
```

Comment: I know you answered first but @ele solution worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Array= [  
        "https://basueUrl.com/Patient",
        "https://basueUrl.com/Organization",
        "https://basueUrl.com/Claim",
        "https://basueUrl.com/Practitioner",
        "https://basueUrl.com/Encounter",
        "https://basueUrl.com/Condition",
        "https://basueUrl.com/Claim",
        "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit",
        "https://basueUrl.com/Claim",
        "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit", 
        "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit"
        ];
        
var filteredArray = Array.filter(item => item !== "https://basueUrl.com/Claim" && item !== "https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit")

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code below.  Hope this helps.

```
// use this array instead on the original.  It creates a new array from the original 
// array.
const newFilteredArray = Array.filter(url => url !== 'https://basueUrl.com/Claim' && 
   url !== 'https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the way you can achieve the above mentioned scenario.

```
arr.filter(ele=>ele!=="https://basueUrl.com/Claim"
&& ele!=="https://basueUrl.com/ExplanationOfBenefit");
```

Comment: May I know the reason , why the answer was given down-vote?

Comment: Sardar Jee no problem with your method, people prefer answered typed here in answer box rather than the picture.

Comment: I see . But people can point it out also , rather than down-voting. Thank you for letting me know Sam , I will keep in mind going forward .